# python -> replace escape character to convert hexa string from 0x to \x

Tags: python, hex, ansi-escape

i'm trying to print ascii or extended ascii character. using this code :

```
print '\xff'.decode('latin-1')
```

it will print ascii #255, but now i want to input using decimal number like this :

```
num=255
myhex=hex(num) 
print myhex.decode('latin-1')
```

It doesn't work coz myhex is '0xff' , so i need to convert into '\xff'. replacing the '0x' with '\x' is giving me error.

```
myhex.replace('0x','\x')
```

will give me error : *ValueError: invalid \x escape*

How to solve the problem? anyone can help ? the goal i want to print char -> ÿ in terminal/console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you're searching for is

```
chr(255)
```

In python2, that gives you a character with binary value 255. If you print that to a terminal that uses UTF8, it will show up as `?` (or similar) because the terminal doesn't know what to do with it. To convert that to it's unicode codepoint, you can `decode` it:

```
chr(255).decode('latin1')
```

In python3, `chr(255)` already gives you the unicode charcter `'LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS'`.

you could also do the same in python2 using

```
unichr(255)
```

Comment: Sorry ,that's not what i'm looking for. print chr(255) will print '?' , i want to display its real asciicharacter in terminal which is -> ÿ sorry  i forgot to mention about that. i edit the question.

Comment: @andio - sorry for misunderstanding your question. adapted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print chr(255).decode("latin-1")
ÿ
```